# Tkinter Canvas itemconfigure

Tags: tkinter, python-3.3

So I have a canvas with a picture on it. I want to click a button that will replace the picture with a different one.

The Canvas code:

```
self.__leftImageCanvas = Canvas(self.__frame3,width = 200, height = 150, bg = 'white')
gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'b.gif')
self.__leftImage = self.__leftImageCanvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
```

The function that edits the picture on the canvas:

```
newgif = PhotoImage(file = '2h.gif')
self.__leftImageCanvas.itemconfigure(self.__leftImage, image = newgif)
self.__leftImageCanvas.image = 'b.gif'
```

I don't understand the last line of code above. It is something I managed to write based on other question/answers.
Now when I purposely make an error in this last line like a syntax error, the canvas picture successfully changes. But if the line of code is error-less, the canvas picture doesn't change,but disappears altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably problem with `PhotoImage` and `Garbage Collector`.

But it rather should be `self.__leftImageCanvas.image = newgif`

--

When you leave function then `PhotoImage` object (`newgif`) is destroyed by `Garbage Collector` so you don't have image in `newgif` and you can't see it on `Canvas`.

Solution is to assign `PhotoImage` object (`newgif`) to global variable or to existing object (for example `self.__leftImageCanvas.image = newgif`)

--

In current code if you have error in function then `Garbage Collector` can't do its job and image (`newgif`) isn't destroyed. When code is correct than `Garbage Collector` removes `newgif` from memory and `Canvas` has no image to display.